# is "messor tempus" the correct translation for time reaper?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

If the answer is no I would like to know what "Time reaper" will translate to in Latin and or if there is anything in Latin language which will translate back into Time reaper.

I used google translate to get this translation. I like the sound of it but don't know if it makes sense in Latin Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the site! It's [good to not trust Google Translate](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4349/what-is-google-translate-good-for) - it does not handle Latin well at all. Could you edit your post to include information on what meaning you want to convey? I would also take a look at our question on [how to ask for a translation](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/483/how-can-i-ask-a-translation-question-if-i-dont-know-any-latin) for more information.

Comment: What is a "time reaper" supposed to be? Google's nonsense can usually be disregarded, but for the record, *messor tempus* means "time the reaper" or "time as a reaper."

Comment: I'll second @SebastianKoppehel. If you can explain some more about what exactly you are trying to convey, it would help others know what to translate.

Comment: magnus: This was a good question featuring "The Reaper"; https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/12594/1982.

Answer (score 4):

If the intended meaning is "reaper of time", then perhaps **messor temporis** will do. It would be a literal translation of that phrase. *Temporis* is the genitive case of *tempus*, indicating "of ...". Depending on what you want to use it for, this could be a good translation, or not. For time is not normally something that one reaps.

Comment: Right -- reaping would probably be literally interpreted by the Romans to mean "harvest." Like in the proverb "you reap what you sew."

Comment: @Nickimite Is there a different definition for "reaper" in English? To reap means to harvest. They are exact synonyms to my ears.

Comment: You're right that the definition of souls is the same. It's about what it implies. It's either harvester (of plants) or harvester (of souls). We tend to assume harvester (of souls), but I meant to say that Romans would probably assume harvester (of plants).