# Gerundial arguments selected by verbs taking Genitive: e.g., "Memento moriendi"? "Me paenitet vivendi"?

Tags: verbs, syntax, genitive, infinitive, gerund

As a follow-up of two previous questions on Latin grammar, I was wondering if examples like *Memento moriendi* (cf. [*Memento mori*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/12644/memento-mori-indirect-speech)) and  *Me paenitet vivendi* (cf. [*Me paenitet vivere*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/11191/what-is-the-grammatical-logic-of-impersonal-constructions-like-me-non-solum-p)) are also attested.

This question is motivated by:

(i) Joonas’s insightful [comment](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/12644/memento-mori-indirect-speech), whose intuition there I tend to share: “*memento mori* and *memento moriendi* mean slightly different things, something like 'remember to die' and 'be mindful of the phenomenon of dying'".

and

(ii) my specific question at the end of a previous [post](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/11191/what-is-the-grammatical-logic-of-impersonal-constructions-like-me-non-solum-p): "(...) e.g., *Me, mi Pomponi, valde paenitet vivere*. (Cic. *Att.* 3,4). As for the latter example, I was wondering why a gerund in genitive case could not instead be used: e.g., *Me paenitet vivendi*".

Answer (score 1):

In Q. [Memento Mori--Revisited](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/12603/1982) offered gerundive (neuter impersonal) alternatives to "memento mori": "nunc est moriendum" = "now must die" & "mox erit moriendum" = "soon one must die". Of course, yourself will recognise these as having been inspired by your own Q:[Nunc est bibendum: gerund or gerundive?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/10809/1982).
The gerundive genitive is a more complex species: "memento moriendi" cannot be translated as "remember one must of dying". The more long-winded gerundive-of-obligation style: 
"Remember it-ought-to-be-(a time)-of-dying/ of-death ("a time" being understood); alternatively: "Remember it-ought-to-be-(a concept)-of-dying/ of-death (again, "a concept" is undertood). This, second one is reminiscent of what Joonas has already said.

These may appeal to literal-translation purists (like me); but, they are clumsy, jerky & rambling. A more succinct offer may be: "miles Romanus, memento mox erit moriendum" = "Roman soldier (rank is now irrelevant) remember soon one must die."
The Romans were well-aware of the rapid passage of time (tempus fugit). This continues to fit with the teachings of Seneca--everyone is dying--a Roman mindset.

The next one: "me paenitet vivendi" = "it makes me sorry of living", it's not a good translation; but, the grammatical rule for impersonal verb paenitet with construction (+ accusative of the person and genitive of the cause) allows for genitive of the cause of the sorrow, here, living.

Comment: I don't think the gerund proposed in the question has any sense of obligation to it. For a certainly attested type of obligation free gerund, one can say *domum redii cenandi causa*. Gerundives can be used similarly.

Comment: As noted by Joonas, the examples in my question above do not involve obligation. However, as pointed out in your answer, things are different when the copula verb _esse_ is present: e.g., _Memento moriendum esse nobis omnibus_

Comment: @Mitomino: Thank you. What is more obligatory than death? Isn't that the whole point, here? Gerund genitive, "moriendi", did not appear to fit: "Remember of-the-dying"; which, can only work if more words are added (understood) than are there already. Is that what Joonas was attempting to achieve (Be-mindful-of-the-phenomenon-of-dying.)? How, then, is this any improvement on the panoply of translations offered in the preceding three Qs? Yes, a pithy, two-word, aphorism is now in its fourth Q. If yourself feels that the answer is unhelpful I'll delete it.

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: Apologies, misunderstood yourself, yesterday.

Comment: @tony Thanks for your comment. You're absolutely right: (un)fortunately, nothing is more obligatory than death. As for my grammar question above, I was wondering if examples like _Me paenitet vivendi_ are attested (along with attested ones like _Me paenitet vivere_). Joonas's intuition is that they could exist (with a slightly different meaning) but I don't know for sure. Hence my question.