# Syntax of sentences with the verb "pudet"

Tags: syntax, verbs, grammar-identification, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata, impersonal

In [Lewis and Short](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/pudeo), I have seen that the verb *pudeo* is chiefly used as an impersonal verb. In fact, I have found some examples of such usage in chapter XXIII of *Lingua latina per se illustrata. Familia Romana*:

> - Puerum pudet factī suī.
> - Is quem factōrum suōrum pudet rubēre solet.

There are other sentences with "pudet" in the same chapter, but it seems to me that, in these other cases, it's not used as an impersonal verb. However, I'm not sure about that. For instance,

> Nōnne tē pudet hoc fecisse?

I interpret *hoc fecisse* as the subject of the verb *pudet*: is this correct?

Another example is the following:

> Profectō mē pudet hoc ā meō filiō factum esse!

In this case, I see *hoc ā meō filiō factum esse* as the subject of *pudet*, but maybe I'm wrong. I think these two clauses work as subjects because of the presence of the pronoun *hoc* which, I believe, is in the nominative case.

So, in the two previous sentences, I see an infinitive clause working as the subject of *pudet* which conveys the reason for being ashamed and an accusative direct object (*tē* and *mē*) that represents the person who is ashamed. Is this interpretation correct?

I'm also trying to understand what is the syntactic structure of the sentences with *pudet* being used as an impersonal verb, as (I believe) in the first two ones in this post. Other examples from Lewis and Short are:

> - PLAUT. *Ep*. 2, 1, 1 (166) sq.: fratris me pudet.
> - CIC. *Verr*. 1, 12, 35: pudet me non tui quidem, sed Chrysippi.

In all these cases, I see a genitive which conveys the reason for being ashamed and an accusative direct object (*puerum*, *quem*, *me*) that represents the person who is ashamed. If I understood correctly, it seems to me that the contents of this [other question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/11191/) confirms what I have stated.

So, my question is: are my interpretations about syntax correct? Is that the usual way to construct sentences with the verb *pudet*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you have seen, the syntax of *pudet*-type verbs is not an easy topic. Here I will limit myself to answering the questions you have included in your post:

- (In the example) "*Nōnne tē pudet hoc fecisse?* I interpret *hoc fecisse* as the subject of the verb *pudet*: is this correct?"

Yes, to the extent that the infinitival clause *hoc fecisse* (NB: here *hoc*-Acc. is the direct object of *fecisse*) can be replaced by a pronoun in the nominative case (e.g. *hoc*-Nom.: cf. *Non te pudet hoc?*), your analysis is correct. That is to say, to the extent that your infinitival clause has the same syntactic function as the subject *haec* (neuter plural nominative) in an attested example like *Non te haec pudent?* (Ter. *Ad.* 754), you are entitled to analyze it as the subject.

- *Profectō mē pudet hoc ā meō filiō factum esse!* In this case, I see *hoc ā meō filiō factum esse* as the subject of *pudet*, but maybe I'm wrong. I think these two clauses work as subjects because of the presence of the pronoun *hoc* which, I believe, is in the nominative case.

Yes, you are right when saying that the infinitival clause can be analyzed as the subject of *pudet*. However, note that you are wrong when saying that the pronoun *hoc* is in the nominative case. No, it is in the accusative case, i.e. *hoc* is the subject of the compound infinitive *factum esse*. NB: it is often assumed that the accusative case of the subject of an infinitival clause is assigned by the main verb but this is not always the case: e.g. cf. *Necesse est te abire* or your example *Me pudet hoc factum esse*. In fact, I would say this situation is more frequent than some people in this site believe...

- So, in the two previous sentences, I see an infinitive clause working as the subject of *pudet* which conveys the reason for being ashamed and an accusative direct object (*tē* and *mē*) that represents the person who is ashamed. Is this interpretation correct?

Yes, your interpretation is correct.

- I'm also trying to understand what is the syntactic structure of the sentences with *pudet* being used as an impersonal verb, as (I believe) in the first two ones in this post (...) In all these cases, I see a genitive which conveys the reason for being ashamed and an accusative direct object (*puerum*, *quem*, *me*) that represents the person who is ashamed. If I understood correctly, it seems to me that the contents of this [other question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/11191/what-is-the-grammatical-logic-of-impersonal-constructions-like-me-non-solum-p?noredirect=1&lq=1) confirm what I have stated.

Yes, what you have said is in tune with what I said in this previous [post](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/11191/what-is-the-grammatical-logic-of-impersonal-constructions-like-me-non-solum-p?noredirect=1&lq=1).

- So, my question is: are my interpretations about syntax correct? Is
  that the usual way to construct sentences with the verb *pudet*?

As I have just said, your interpretations of the syntax of this verb are correct. The only relevant mistake I have noticed in your post is your saying that *hoc* is in the nominative case in an example like *me pudet hoc ā meō filiō factum esse*. As noted, here *hoc* is in the accusative case since it is the subject of the infinitive *factum esse*. As for your last question, the usual way (i.e. the impersonal one!) to construct sentences with the verb *pudet* can indeed be nicely exemplified with the two attested examples you have given from Plautus and Cicero.

To conclude, the usual way to construct sentences with a psychological verb like *pudet* in Early and Classical Latin is through this impersonal construction (with the Experiencer in the accusative case and with the Stimulus in the genitive case). However, things changed in Late Latin, when the personal construction (i.e. with the Experiencer in the nominative case) turned out to be more prominent. In tune with this change, in Romance languages the Latin impersonal construction with *pudet* came to be replaced by the pronominal/reflexive one: e.g. cf. Cat. *avergonyir-se*, Sp. *avergonzarse*, It. *vergognarsi* ‘to feel shame’, i.a.

For those of you who are interested in having more information about Latin psychological verbs, take a look at this book. Note that chapter 4 (pages 119-189) is exclusively dedicated to the "*me pudet* construction":

[Fedriani, Chiara (2014). *Experiential Constructions in Latin*. Leiden. Boston: Brill.](https://brill.com/display/title/24526)

Comment: I see... So, but if *hoc* is the subject of the passive construction *hoc ā meō filiō factum esse*, shouldn't be *hoc* in the nominative case?

Comment: And, in your example *Non te pudet hoc?*, shouldn't genitive *huius* be used instead of *hoc*? I have the same problem with the example by Terence.

Comment: @Charo As noted above, _hoc_ is the subject of the infinitival subordinate clause in _Profectō mē pudet hoc ā meō filiō factum esse_. However, note that _hoc_ in this example is in the accusative case, i.e. note that the subordinate clause _hoc ā meō filiō factum esse_ can be considered a nice example of an _Accusativus cum Infinitivo_ construction. In contrast, note that _hoc_ can indeed be in the nominative case in another example (in the personal infinitive construction) _Hoc ā meō filiō factum esse videtur_ but not in your example where the infinitival clause depends on the verb _pudet_.

Comment: @Charo _in your example Non te pudet hoc?, shouldn't genitive huius be used instead of hoc?_ It's a very good question, Charo! As noted at the end of the post of mine you have linked, the stimulus of _pudet_-type verbs is in the nominative case iff this is a neuter pronoun. Note that something similar happens when the stimulus is the infinitive: _Me, mi Pomponi, valde paenitet vivere_ (Cic. Att. 3,4), instead of _Me paenitet vivendi_ (cf. https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/12655/gerundial-arguments-selected-by-verbs-taking-genitive-e-g-memento-moriendi?noredirect=1&lq=1 ).