# How do I say "Remember death, but do not forget to live" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, verbs, sentence-translation

it's been a few years since I was in a Latin class, but I've been wanting to get a tattoo in the language for a while now, and "Remember death, but do not forget to live" is the phrase I've decided on.

Using what limited knowledge I still have and some googling, I've come up with:

"Memento mori, autem noli oblivisci vivere"

The fact that I'm using two infinitives in a row is setting off my "this is wrong" detectors, and I was hoping someone could guide me in the right direction.
Thanks!

Comment: "Memento mori" means "Remember to die!", it is also rendered in other ways described in Q: https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/12603/1982. You need the noun, "death" = "mors"; giving "Memento mortem...".

Comment: @tony Shouldn't that be "memento mortis"?

Comment: @gmvh: Defective verb "memini"  can take the genitive or accusative, therefore you are equally correct.

Comment: @tony: doesn't that alter the meaning? I seem to recall that the accusative implies that it is something you simply have in your memory, whereas actively remembering is denoted by the genitive.

Comment: @gmvh: Death and its inevitability will be in everyone's memory/ mind. The expression seeks to stir it up a little. I was unaware of this difference.

Comment: Did you get the tattoo? I'm getting one similar

Answer (score 3):

Your translation is actually almost perfect. The only small issue is that *autem* "however" never stands first in its clause; it would be better replaced with *sed* or *at*, both of which mean "but".

The reason there are two infinitives in a row is that one way of expressing a negative command is *noli* plus infinitive, and in this case that infinitive "forget" then takes a further infinitive "live". If you want to avoid this, there are other ways of forming negative commands, such as *ne* plus subjunctive. This would give:

*Memento mori, sed/at ne obliviscaris vivere*.

This construction is a bit more poetic in tone, so might also be suitable for that reason. You could play with the word order in various ways, for example with chiasmus:

*Memento mori, sed/at vivere ne obliviscaris*.

Comment: The requirement is "remember death"--blunt & chilling. The use of "memento mori" is long-winded: "remember-that-you-are-mortal" and has a lesser impact. Do you agree?

Comment: @tony It works best with two parallel structures, so I'd say it should be either *mori&vivere* or *mors&vita*. Perhaps the verbs are somewhat more active. The phrase *memento mori* doesn't have a perfect English counterpart; both "remember death" and "remember that you are mortal" work. It's indeed blunt in Latin.

Comment: @tony It's only the English translation that's long-winded; *memento mori* is slightly shorter than *memento mortis*, for whatever that's worth.

Comment: The carpe diem poem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpe_diem has it all, in a personal form. The memento mori comes as a brutal Roman ritual during the triumphal processions and has no connection to the Epicurean motto.