# Translation Request, English to Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary, translation-check, sentence-translation, english

How can I translate this sentence to Latin, "Man in the palace! Remember death, live with fear of death. Leave us alone."

I translate like that but... I don't know, I guess, I did a mistake. My translation is:
"Homo in regia fecisset! Memento mori, advivo Timor Mortis. Noli nos molestiamo."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest:

> Homo in palatio! Memento mori, semper sis in metu mortis. Ne diutius nos vexes.

A few points:

- *Regia* is short for *domus regia*, which literally means “royal house.” So it is a palace all right, but a king's or queen's palace. (Or at least I would say this word has a strong association with royalty.) I preferred *palatio* here because it is the root of “palace.” It has an association with the imperial court in Rome on the Palatine (one of the seven hills of Rome), but was transferred to other contexts as well.
- I'd like to know what process of translation led to the word *fecisset* appearing in that sentence  It does not belong there.
- *Memento mori* – well, that needs no introduction. It does not literally mean “remember death” (what does it mean then? [glad you asked](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/89/what-does-memento-mori-actually-mean)!), but it is well known and a good fit nonetheless.
- *Semper sis in metu mortis* literally means “may you always be in fear of death.” *Metus* and *timor* both mean fear, and the difference is small (they are often used together: *metus ac timor* etc.), but *metus* is ultimately the [better fit](https://www.latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries?t=do533) in my opinion.
- *Ne nos vexes* – *noli* is [quite polite](https://www.latinitium.com/blog/how-to-tell-someone-not-to-do-something-in-latin), it would be more like “would you please leave us alone.” *Molestiamo* is Italian …